# Ruby Regex Odd Error, What is going on?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following program:

```
class Matcher
  include Enumerable
  def initialize(string, match)
    @string = string
    @match = match
  end

  def each
    @string.scan(/[@#match]/) do |pattern|
      yield pattern
    end
  end
end

mch = Matcher.new("the quickbrown fox", "aeiou")
puts mch.inject {|x, n| x+n}
```

It is supposed to match the characters, `aeiou` with the string `the quickbrown fox`

No matter what I put as the pattern, it oddly prints out the characters: `thc`. What's going on?

Comment: typo or poor syntax ? @#match

Comment: Clearly the regex is a stoner.

Comment: I'm sorry…A couple minutes ago, it said I had to wait for two minutes before doing so. I got up to get a drink. I apologize for not being at the computer checking SO every second of the day, did not know I had to do that.

Comment: @Anonymous You don't *have* to, but it's good courtesy to accept answers that solve your problem so as to give the answerer the credit they deserve `:)`.

Comment: @Anonymous, everything is fine, you don't need to check SO every second, its perfectly fine to leave  a question open for a day or two to see if there is maybe a better answer. Its the other way round, its not OK to push you to accept an answer. (And that only 25 minutes after you asked!!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@string.scan(/[@#match]/) do |pattern|` is incorrect. `#{@match}` is what you're looking for.

Comment: You can actually just do `#@match`.

Comment: @andrew Sure, but you can't do @#match.

Comment: Just clarifying that that wasn't the part I was pointing out.